# Lost connection to server with show create function

Tags: mysql, sql, database-connection

I've seen the familiar Lost connection to MySQL server during query error before, with large data sets and the like. What I've not seen, but am now seeing, is that message when running `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION`. The function is only about 20 lines long and seems to have no syntax errors. I am able to drop and recreate it without issue (using a definition from a back up). If I create the same function with a different name, I get no error. But with the original name, I get the error. What can I do to fix this?

The function in question:

```
DELIMITER$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `check_address`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `check_address`(
    _loan_id BIGINT,
    _address1 VARCHAR(255),
    _address2 VARCHAR(255),
    _city VARCHAR(255),
    _state VARCHAR(255),
    _zip VARCHAR(255)
    ) RETURNS tinyint(1)
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE _cur_address1 VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE _cur_address2 VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE _cur_city VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE _cur_state VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE _cur_zip VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE _is_ok TINYINT(1);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN SET _is_ok = NULL; END;
    
    SELECT
        property_address.address_1,
        property_address.address_2,
        property_address.city,
        property_address.state_abrv,
        property_address.zip_id
    INTO 
        _cur_address1,
        _cur_address2,
        _cur_city,
        _cur_state,
        _cur_zip
    FROM property_address WHERE property_address.loan_id = _loan_id;
    
    SELECT  IF(LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _cur_address1)) = LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _address1)), 0, 1) +
        IF(LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _cur_address2)) = LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _address2)), 0, 1) +
        IF(LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _cur_city)) = LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _city)), 0, 1) +
        IF(LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _cur_state)) = LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _state)), 0, 1) +
        IF(LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _cur_zip)) = LOWER(TRIM(BOTH FROM _zip)), 0, 1)
    INTO _is_ok;
    
    RETURN _is_ok;
    
END$$
```

EDIT: additional fun details:

These work:

- `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION dbname.check_address;`
- `` SHOW CREATE FUNCTION dbname.`check_address`; ``
- `` SHOW CREATE FUNCTION `dbname`.check_address; ``

This doesn't:

- `` SHOW CREATE FUNCTION `dbname`.`check_address`; ``

Output of `mysql --version` (yes, it's old -- not under my control):

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35-80.0, for Linux (x86_64) using  5.1
```

Comment: Wow, this makes no sense. Delimiting identifiers in back-ticks doesn't change the way an SQL statement executes or the result it returns. It's only used in parsing. I've never seen what you describe. I'd suggest looking in the MySQL Server error log to see if it's encountering an assertion and restarting the mysqld process.

Comment: @BillKarwin: heading that way. BTW, on another database (of which this one is an exact copy), I *do not* have the same issue. The backticks don't make a difference.

Comment: Do you see the same issue when showing other functions? That is, losing connection if you delimit both schema and function but not with other combinations of delimiting?

Comment: @BillKarwin Most other functions are fine. Some are not. I can't determine any pattern.

Comment: Another question: What client do you use when you see this issue? Is it the `mysql` client or some GUI like Workbench, or some other connector code? I'm wondering if the query could be rewritten by some code in the client before it is sent to the MySQL Server. (edit: Oh, I see you did mention `mysql` client, that answers my question)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Unless there's a clue in the error log, all I can suggest is the doctor's advice from the old joke: Man goes to the doctor and says "it hurts when I do this" and swings his arms around. The doctor says, "then don't do that."

Comment: @BillKarwin This is actually happening just in SQLyog. I am not, as I thought I had been able to, replicate it in the mysql client on the server. I don't have a mysql client on my local machine to verify. I'm wondering if it's a connection parameter issue? There are a lot of knobs. I can check any you think would be relevant.

Comment: @BillKarwin Unfortunately, because we're using Yog's schema diff tool, which offers no control over quoting, I have to fix this somehow.

Comment: Okay, then this is probably a bug in SQLYog. Maybe it's doing some kind of query rewrite, or else it's not handling the result set correctly. Anyway, this doesn't seem to be a coding problem, it's just a tech support problem with a commercial application. I suggest you contact Webyog.

Comment: @BillKarwin it may or may not be (b/c I don't have a MySQL client installed locally to verify whether it is Yog or something else), but in any case, it's now clear that it's very specific to the crappy set up here.

Comment: @BillKarwin: using MySQL workbench, I can confirm I get the same issue. It's not a Yog problem after all.